# The origin of the Trinity

Tags: trinity

Where and when was the concept of the Trinity first conceived? Was it modeled after the Romans Triune pagan Gods? Who implemented the teaching of a Christian triune
god? When and where was it first taught? How long did it take for the doctrine that God is a triune God to become saturated in the Christian belief/church?

I prefer to have documents, articles that can and will substantiate your position on this question Not..... That is what I have always been told, taught, or instructed or scripture from this or that bible version. Unless it comes from a Septuagint, manuscript, uncial, etc.. etc.  I am looking for Historic proof from the fifth century back to the day of the messiah's birth.

Keep in mind that, according to the written word the Christian God can not be contradictory or confusing in any part of his character.  ie. Nu 23:19 God is not a man, that he should lie; neither the son of man, that he should repent: hath he said, and shall he not do it? or hath he spoken, and shall he not make it good?

1Co 14:33

> For God is not the author of confusion, but of peace, as in all churches of the saints. {confusion: Gr. tumult, or, unquietness}

Mal 3:6

> For I am the LORD, I change not; therefore ye sons of Jacob are not consumed.

The word *changed* is [8138](https://biblehub.com/greek/8138.htm).  *hnv  shanah,  shaw-naw'*

> a primitive root; to fold, i.e. duplicate (literally or figuratively); by implication, to transmute (transitive or intransitive):--do (speak, strike) again, alter, double, (be given to) change, disguise, (be) diverse, pervert, prefer, repeat, return, do the second time.

Joh 16:13

> Howbeit when he, the Spirit of truth, is come, he will guide you into all truth: for he shall not speak of himself; but whatsoever he shall hear, that shall he speak: and he will shew you things to come.

The word *spirit* is [4151](https://biblehub.com/greek/4151.htm).  *pneuma  pneuma,  pnyoo'-mah*

> from [4154](https://biblehub.com/greek/4154.htm); a current of air, i.e. breath (blast) or a breeze; by analogy or figuratively, a spirit, i.e. (human) the rational soul, (by implication) vital principle, mental disposition, etc., or (superhuman) an angel, demon, or (divine) God, Christ's spirit, the Holy Spirit:--ghost, life, spirit(-ual, -ually), mind. Compare [5590](https://biblehub.com/greek/5590.htm).

Comment: "after the Romans Triune pagan Gods" What Roman Triune pagan Gods? I suspect from this phrasing you either a) don't understand what is meant by the Trinity or b) you don't know Roman paganism very much